# align a set of UILabels and UITextFields

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uilabel

I'm facing a problem and I think I'd ask for a better solution.

Problem: I have some UILabels and UITextfields that are generated dynamically from a sentence, e.g. I would like the user to choose among 'come', 'came', 'comed' to fill in 'I've _ _ _ _ _ to talk to you'. The '_ _ _ _ _' will be rendered as textfield (click on it will trigger a picker view). And there might be more slots in one sentence. I want to show the sentence in multiple lines, with the textfields in between.

Current solution: I separate the slots and literal parts, calculate the length of each part and append textfields behind them, if the length of the textfield plus the length of the existing literal part exceeds the total width of the screen, the textfield is moved to the next line. But, the solution is not always working. Sometimes the length is calculated wrong and in the end I got one letter missing at the end of some line.

Has anyone done something similar before? I will be happy to see some easier and safer method for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at auto-layout and constraints. They make this sort of thing much more straightforward. You would build a few constraints that set your desired geometry, and the system would enforce those constraints for you.

Comment: I noticed the new "constraints" as I updated my xcode4 to 5. but looks to me they are set in interface builder. I think constraints is the way to go but could you provide a sample or a link?

Comment: ok found one myself: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_iOS_6_Auto_Layout_Constraints_in_Code